# Upload data to multisample texture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I want to upload data from CPU to a multisample 2D texture in OpenGL. For 2D texture I could use the function:

```
void glTexSubImage2D(   GLenum target,
GLint level,
GLint xoffset,
GLint yoffset,
GLsizei width,
GLsizei height,
GLenum format,
GLenum type,
const GLvoid * pixels);
```

to push data from pixels to the texture. How can I do the same thing for multisample 2D texture?

Comment: Does the data you have contain values per sample? Or only per pixel?

Comment: It has data per sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't acces the image data of multisample textures via the client side of OpenGL. The only way around that is by using shaders and/or FBOs.

Conceptually, you can render a full-screen quad to a multisample texture and in the fragment shader, use `gl_SampleID` to determine which sample you are currently writing to. In combination with the `gl_FragCoord`, you can for example index into an TBO which holds the raw per-sample value you want to store in the texture.

However, as the sample locations are completely under the GL's control it is questionable if this operation is of any use. YMMV.